# PHP - conditional statements

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$thumbnail_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $thumbnail_filename) &&
    //move desktop files
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1280x800) &&
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1366x768) &&
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1920x1080]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1920x1080)){

    echo "<p>We can move all files.</p>";}
```

In my code above the text is not printed when one of the conditions fail, and that is because of && which means all needs to be true, what I want to achieve here is when any of the file is selected to upload it should go through the condition and print the text, and if any one or two of the files is not selected it can skip and still print the text since one file is existing, and if no file is selected then the condition should be false. It can't be done with || since with that if one is true everything is true, so what combination can be used to do this?

For example
thumbail file moved = ture

desktop file 1280x800 moved = ture

desktop file 1366x768 **not moved** = false //from here it should test the next condition

desktop file 1920x1080 moved = true

//and should print the output.

Comment: want to execute the condition at one time, don't want to break it into many ifs..

Comment: The question seems very vague. Could you rephrase?

Comment: To clarify: You want the "thumbnail" and _at least one of the "desktop" files_ uploaded, in order to print your text?

Comment: yes, but I'm thinking || will work..haha!

Comment: If that's the case, `||` won't work, because if one "desktop" file is uploaded but no thumbnail, it will pass the test. Also, as [@hek2mgl suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876871/php-conditional-statments#comment29568229_19876995), not all `move_uploaded_file()` calls are guaranteed to be executed, due to [_short-circuit evaluation_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @veptemp What is wrong with my answer? It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
// trys to upload the thumbnail
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$thumbnail_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $thumbnail_filename)
  // and tries to upload all the other images and store the return values.  
  // if one or more of them succeeded print the message
  && in_array(TRUE, array(
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1280x800),
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1366x768),
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1920x1080]['tmp_name'],$desktop_filename_1920x1080)
))) {
    echo 'upload done';
} else {
    echo 'no upload happened';
}
```

Comment: I think [he wants "thumbnail" to be mandatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876871/php-conditional-statments#comment29568275_19876871).

Comment: @veptemp Now it should do what you want. However, the code in question is not  real world usable. Usually you need to know what exactly happended and craft at least a proper message (or error message)...

Comment: @geomagas thx :) .. wasn't easy to get what OP want's... :) still think the code is - although working and maybe nice looking - relatively useless as usually one would like to know exactly what happens (for post processing, validation, ...) (like I said)

Comment: I read you. However, that's another question's answer. Keep it up!

Comment: @hek2mgl, how about if I want to make the existing ones mandatory not just the thumbnail? I mean the one user selected to upload.. _(Special Note: still the thumbnail is super mandatory.)_